# Get data from qtablewidget in 2d array

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have `Qtablewidget` and a `PushButton`. When a button pressed I want that data(flot number) in `Qtablewidget` exctracted/trandformed(dont know how to describe it) in 2d array and then pass to previously made function.

I created a cycle:

```
    def DoSomething(self):
        for i in range(self.ui.Level_N.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.ui.Level_N.columnCount()):
                T=self.ui.Level_N.item(i,j).text()
        print (T)
```

But it prints only last element of table. I know that I should somehow print that `T` is 2d array, but I dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the "top level" list outside of the main loop, and each "row" outside of the inner one.

Note that you should *always* check that `item()` is valid before calling its methods, because unless the item value was edited by the user (or set in Designer) or explicitly set with `setItem()`, it will return `None` and you'll get an `AttributeError`.

You should also decide how to deal with non existing items or items that don't contain numeric values. In the following example, I used 0 as a fallback value.

```py
def doSomething(self):
    array = []
    for i in range(self.ui.Level_N.rowCount()):
        row = []
        array.append(row)
        for j in range(self.ui.Level_N.columnCount()):
            item = self.ui.Level_N.item(i,j)
            if item:
                try:
                    row.append(float(item.text()))
                except TypeError:
                    row.append(0)
            else:
                row.append(0)
    print(array)
```

Comment: Just cheked, always print 0. Tested on int and float numbers

Comment: I forgot the parentheses of `text()`. Check again.

Comment: yep, working thx